# Parsing degree/minute/second field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, coordinates

I am working in a tabular set (.dbf) In ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 with an odd DMS format.The format is as follows:

```
Lat: 45585400
Long: 89560600
```

I believe this is a strange notation for 45°58'54" and -89°56'06". My problem is I can't figure out how to parse the Degrees, Minutes and Seconds out into individual fields in the .dbf. Once I get that far I can easily convert the value to decimal degrees and create point data out of it.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming that the input is a double, long, or string. If the input is a string, you can remove the line that casts the value to a string.

```python
exp = """
def convert(value,latlong):
    num = str(int(value))
    i = 0 if len(num) == 8 else 1
    val = int(num[0:2+i]) + int(num[2+i:4+i])/60.0 + int(num[4+i:])/360000.0
    if latlong.lower() in ["longitude", "long", "lambda"]: val = -val    
    return val"""

arcpy.CalculateField_management("<DBF FILE>", "<new lat field>", 
                                'convert(!LAT!,"")', "PYTHON_9.3", exp)
```

With built in exp, it's difficult to maintain exact spacing and newline characters.

```python
arcpy.CalculateField_management("<DBF FILE>", "<new lat field>", 
                                'convert(!LAT!,"")', "PYTHON_9.3",
                                """def convert(value,latlong):\n    num = str(int(value))\n    i = 0 if len(num) == 8 else 1\n    val = int(num[0:2+i]) + int(num[2+i:4+i])/60.0 + int(num[4+i:])/360000.0\n    if latlong.lower() in ["longitude", "long", "lambda"]: val = -val\n    return val""")
```